# German slang websites similar to urbandictionary.com

Tags: slang, dictionary, online-resource, resource

I use [this site](http://www.urbandictionary.com/) quit a a lot, especially for English scene forums or chats.

Anyone knows a similar site/online database for German slang words? Or translation service which shows at least well-known slang words?

Comment: Note that urbandictionary.com contains German terms itself! For example http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=K%C3%B6rperklaus

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### [Mundmische:](http://mundmische.de/)

> mundmische.de ist eine einzigartige Sammlung deutscher Umgangssprache und Sprichwörter. Hier kann jeder seinen Wortschatz erweitern bzw. verbreiten.

Answer (score 4):

I only know of such a site for austrian terms: [ostarrichi.org](http://www.ostarrichi.org/)

Answer (score 3):

[Sprachnudel.de](http://www.sprachnudel.de/) is another candidate.

Answer (score 1):

I did it, here's what you want https://germanslang.de/

Comment: (Unclear for me is only the introduction as it seems JohnJonta is the other of linked website - yet some previous listings also only link to the page as it is impossible to include "essential parts" of an online dictionary)

Comment: I don't understand the comments and the delete vote: OP is asking for website references, and this answer provides a link to such a website.

Answer (score 0):

I know very few North American English slang words and phrases, much less their German equivalent.  That being said, however, I think the American Google's website "*translate.google.com*", (one that I depend on because it serves me just like an old-school 'blackboard' used to do), could be of use for translations of German/English slang words and phrases.  And that website especially if you want to jot down and have translated some word or phrase, in English or German, that briefly or unexpectedly comes into your head.

The website works well for me when I need translations (and also cross-translations) of Google's replies to/from standard German and English.  And that same capability is available for translating to/from a large number of *other* languages which can be used for input/output queries and answers.

A really nice added advantage of Google's translation website is its ability to *properly pronounce* individual words, phrases, or complete sentences -- if the sentences are relatively short.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this website yet: https://www.onlinesprache.de/?

Comment: Everyone please be aware that excessive - or often even subtle - usage of this kind of language can be an excellent way to make yourself a perfect idiot ;-)