# Ursprung von "Nicht verzagen, ... fragen"

Tags: etymology, expression

Bei einer Diskussion kamen wir letztens auf den Ausspruch

> Nicht verzagen, [Name] fragen.

zu sprechen. Aus purer Neugierde überlege ich nun, ob das ein Zitat ist oder einfach nur eine aufgrund des Reimes griffige und häufig benutzte Kollokation. Hat das einen bekannten Ursprung, wie z.B. einen bekannten Dichter, der es verbreitet hat?

Comment: Es gibt eine Fernsehserie aus 1964 namens "Nicht verzagen - Stangl fragen", aber ich weiß nicht, ob das der Ursprung dieser Redewendung ist, oder nur eine bekannt Redewendung als Titel verwendet wurde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naja, ob das jetzt die grosse schöpferische Reimkunst war sei dahingestellt :) Mich erinnert *verzagen* auch zuerst an Gedichte. Aber diese spezielle Reim ist dann wohl eher in einer Kneipe entstanden, auf das Jahrhundert will ich mich nicht festlegen

Änliche Sprüche hat wohl schon sinngemäss [Seneca geklopft](http://www.zeno.org/Wander-1867/A/Verzagen?hl=nicht%20verzagen):

> Man muss nicht gleich verzagen, immer wieder wagen.

*nicht verzagen* taucht in recht vielen Gedichten scheinbar auf, [hier](http://www.zeno.org/Zeno/0/Suche?q=%22nicht%20verzagen%22&k=Bibliothek) siehst du auch schnell zugehörige Jahreszahlen. [Oder hier](http://gedichte.xbib.de/gedicht_suche.html)

Ansonsten vielleicht mal Spruchseiten im Netz durchsuchen (Aphorismen,Zitate), auf die Schnelle hab ich da nix gefunden.

[German slang websites similar to urbandictionary.com](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/german-slang-websites-similar-to-urbandictionary-com) bietet auch noch viele Suchmaschinen

Comment: Ich wollte keinem Dichter unterstellen, so etwas verzapft zu haben. :-) Vielen Dank für die Anregungen zur weiteren Eigenrecherche und Wissensergänzung!