# Wo kann man Wörterbücher finden, in denen moderne Wörter stehen?

Tags: dictionary

Gibt es neue deutsche Wörterbücher, die man benutzen könnte, wo moderne Wörter stehen, wie zum Beispiel : Bitcoin, Selfie, Emojicon usw. ? Ich habe in ganz Internet gesurft und keine gefunden. Habt ihr Vorschläge?

Comment: related http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/german-slang-websites-similar-to-urbandictionary-com - but only mundmische lists "Selfie" but not the others.

Comment: »Ich habe *in ganz Internet* gesurft« ist grammatisch falsch. Das Internet ist kein Name einer geografischen Region wie »Rom«, »Japan« oder »Afrika«, sondern eher eine Behälters wie »Schrank«, »Haus« oder »Müllhalde«. Daher kannst du »*in ganz* Rom«, »*in ganz* Japan« und »*in ganz* Afrika« etwas machen, aber »*im ganzen* Schrank«, »*im ganzen* Haus« und »*in der ganzen* Müllhalde«. Und daher kannst du »*im ganzen* Internet« surfen (was dir wegen der Größe des Internets aber niemand glauben wird), aber eben nicht »in ganz Internet«.

Comment: Wörterbücher sind Bücher und Bücher sind für die meisten Menschen noch immer aus Papier, daher wirst du Wörterbücher am ehesten in einem Buchgeschäft finden. Wenn du eine Online-Übersetzungshilfe suchen solltest, dann solltest du den Begriff »Wörterbuch« vermeiden.

Comment: Das [Urban Dictionary](http://de.urbandictionary.com) erlaubt auch Einträge zu deutschen Lemmata (sowohl auf Deutsch als auch auf Englisch), ist aber (auch nach Wegfiltern der Spaßantworten) längst nicht so vollständig und damit nützlich wie für englische Slangbegriffe und (oft kurzlebige) Neologismen.

Answer (score 1):

Für ganz moderne Wörter hilft die "Wikipedia-Übersetzung": Artikel zum englischen Wort in Wikipedia suchen, links in der Navigationsleiste auf "Deutsch" klicken, und der deutsche Artikel enthält dann die dazu passenden deutschen Begriffe im modernen Sprachgebrauch.

Das funktioniert für Bitcoin (-> Bitcoin), Selfie (-> Selfie), Emojicon (-> Emoji, Emoticon).

Comment: Die Idee, Wikipedia dafür zu benutzen ist zwar gut (daher +1), aber der OP sucht, wenn ich ihn richtig interpretiere, ein Wörter-BUCH aus Papier.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Da er im ganzen Internet gesurft hat, scheint das Internet offenbar auch einen Option zu sein...